# MSTP with looped port

Tags: ethernet, loopback, stp

I have a configuration with two switches connected via a single Ethernet port.
A second port of the first switch is looped back (Tx connected to Rx).
They have 10 MSTI configured on VLAN from 100 to 1000 with step 100. These VLAN are configured on both the ports in the first switch and on the single port of the second one.

The resulting configuration is that the two ports in the first switch are forwarding for the 10 MSTI instances but the looped port is blocked in the CIST (the other one is forwarding also for the CIST).

Is this correct?
Further, as a direct consequent question coming from this configuration, should a BPDU coming into a switch on the port it was originated (due to a loopback) be filtered, from a standard point of view, or not?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a particularly practical problem.. homework?  Which switch is the root bridge?

Comment: on the contrary: it is a real network problem. Actually the network is a little more complicated, as there is an SDH over WDM network between the switches. The user made a loopback in the DWDM network and was sure that the involved port in the switch would have been blocked by STP.  

Before the loopback the root bridges are the first bridge for CIST and even MSTI's  and the second one for odd MSTI's

After the loopback the root bridge is the first switch for all the instances